# How can I grab the second column from a semicolon separated txt file?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have some data in a text file, e.g:

```
02.02.2015;17:03;86;Normal;----;2
02.02.2015;17:07;3;Normal;----;2
02.02.2015;17:07;61;Normal;----;1
02.02.2015;18:04;66;Normal;----;2
02.02.2015;19:26;37;Normal;----;2
02.02.2015;21:17;57;Normal;----;1
03.02.2015;07:17;54;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;48;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;38;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;4;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;80;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;66;Normal;----;2
03.02.2015;07:17;97;Normal;----;2
```

I have show this record. I need only time row, but I want to select time in array like:

```
07:40 as $string[0];
07:42 as $string[1];
07:43 as $string[1];
```

I tried:

```
$string = array();
foreach($Zeit as $key => $time) {
    $string[] = $time; 
}
  echo  $string[0];
```

But code showing error like:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in // $string

This is my current code:

```
$file = "0215.txt";
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);

        $Datum = $data[0]; // Date
        $Zeit = $data[1]; // Time
        $Pers_Nr = $data[2]; // Person number
        $Art = $data[3]; // Non-use
        $Eingabe = $data[4]; // Non-use
        $Terminal = $data[5]; // Non-use

        if($Datum == '02.02.2015' && $Pers_Nr == '17'){

             echo $Zeit.'<br>';

            /*  $string = array();
                foreach($Zeit as $key => $time){
                    $string[] = $time; 
                }
                echo  $string[0];    */
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

How can I only grab the second column from my file into one array? (Note that I only want to grab the value under certain conditions: `if($Datum == '02.02.2015' && $Pers_Nr == '17')`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just read your file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and then loop though all lines with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) each line by `;` as delimiter and just return the second index.

```
<?php

    $lines = file("test.txt");
    $times = array_map(function($v){
        return explode(";", $v)[1];
    }, $lines);

    print_r($times);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 17:03
    [1] => 17:07
    [2] => 17:07
    //...
    [10] => 07:17
    [11] => 07:17
    [12] => 07:17
)
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to append a condition, when you want to grab the time and when not, just simply add it in the anonymous function from [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and return an empty string for those times which you don't want, so that you can filter those values out with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$times = array_filter(array_map(function($v){
    $data = explode(";", $v);
    if(strcmp($data[0], "02.02.2015") === 0 && $data[2] == "3")
        return $data[1];
    return "";
}, $lines));
```

Comment: i wanna select time by date and person id